# Laraval Policies "This action is unauthorized" response message too long

Tags: laravel, error-handling, authorization

I'm using Laravel 8 for a personal project. I use Policy to manage who can do what. I have the view method in the policy like this:

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can view the model.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $passed
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
 */
public function view(User $user, User $passed)
{
    return $user->id == $passed->id;
}
```

When the policy returns error, so I can't view the user, the API response is not just "This action is unauthorized" but something like this:

> {
> "message": "This action is unauthorized.",
> "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException",
> "file": "C:\Users\fabri\Desktop\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php",
> "line": 387,
> "trace": [ with all trace here ]
> }

Why Laravel shows me all and not just "This action is unauthorized"?

Thank you so much for your attention!

Comment: disable debug mode to get the "pretty" response

Answer (score 2):

Those are the debug information. Laravel applications show them when debug mode is enabled. You can disable it by changing `APP_DEBUG=true` to `APP_DEBUG=false` from the `.env` file in the laravel root directory.

Comment: Thank you very much, I apologize if I'm writing this now but most likely, back in the day, I had forgotten to do it